# Difference between tce.api.here.com and fleet.ls.hereapi.com

Tags: here-api

i am modifying my code to use the new apiKey instead of app_code and i have a problem with the new https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/tollcost service.

When i try to feed a route bigger than 600-800 linkID's i am getting the following error:

414 Request-URI Too Large

I dont have any problems with the old service.

I was trying to reduce the linkID count but the result is altered too. 
Can i somehow compress the list of linkID's ?

Comment: Can you share the request with bigger amount of linkID's?

Comment: its working now, i will monitor and compare with the toll costs from fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TCE API(tce.api.here.com) is legacy api and deprecated (but is still in functionality status) and will be not improved and not bug-fixed.

Please use the [Fleet Telematics API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/fleet-telematics/dev_guide/index.html) to calculate toll cost instead of TCE API.

Fleet Telematics API is being improved and supported.